# Dynamics CRM + field type to store shareholders information

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a requirement in which I am getting company's information from an external webapi and  I need to store that data in CRM.

Problem is the users want the shareholders information to be stored in CRM However a company can have huge number of shareholders which we don't want to create as separate record and store in CRM

Is there a way that I could create a field of type say 'Text' and store shareholders name and type in it? Not sure if text length has limitations?

Or is there any other field type which I can create directly on Main table and show shareholders name & type returned from webapi

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dynamics (dataverse) you have 2 options for Text type field.
single line Text: This field can contain up to 4,000 text characters
Multi line Text: This field can contain up to 1,048,576 text characters.

[MS Docs for the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/types-of-fields?view=op-9-1)

If I understand correct, what you really want is to hold information of shareholders (which may be related to your contact or account) but you just do not want to duplicate (create them in CRM) as they are already available in your external system.

[There is something in dynamics called virtual tables (virtual entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/virtual-entities/get-started-ve) Take a look at it, this will not store data in crm but rather fetch it on fly (using Retrieve/retrieve multiple) plugin messages. You will have to take care of it's coding (how to retrive and show), but microsoft recently made it really easy to access. In addtion you can perfrom CURD operation on your virtual table records, you can also link (associate) records to let's say your account/contact or any crm entity.

Comment: did you managed to solve it?